# How to make Linux spi write multi-bytes in one transfer?

Tags: linux, spi, drive

I am using a kit of TI's AM3354, which is quite similar to Beagle Bone Black. And I test it, found that it can only send 4-bytes at most for one transfer, which I mean the spi-cs signal asserted and deasserted. 
But when I change the variable `bits` to be more than 32 like below, the running result shows error.
My question is how to make spi send 64 bits or even more bits for each spi transfer?
Thanks!

```
# ./a.out
open device: /dev/spidev2.0
set spi mode: 0
set bits per word: 40
set max speed: 48000000 Hz (48 MHz)
can't send spi message
: Invalid argument
Aborted


# ./a.out
open device: /dev/spidev2.0
set spi mode: 0
set bits per word: 64
set max speed: 48000000 Hz (48 MHz)
can't send spi message
: Invalid argument
Aborted
```

The test code is below:

```
/*
 * SPI testing utility (using spidev driver)
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2007  MontaVista Software, Inc.
 * Copyright (c) 2007  Anton Vorontsov <avorontsov@ru.mvista.com>
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License.
 *
 * Cross-compile with cross-gcc -I/path/to/cross-kernel/include
 */

#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))

static void pabort(const char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    abort();
}

static const char *device = "/dev/spidev2.0";
static uint8_t mode;
static uint8_t bits = 64;
static uint32_t speed = 48000000;
static uint16_t delay;

static void transfer(int fd)
{
    int ret;
    uint8_t tx[] = {0x31, 0x32, 0x12, 0x89,
                    0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36};
    uint8_t rx[ARRAY_SIZE(tx)] = {0, }; //the comma here doesn't matter, tested by Tom Xue
    struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
        .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
        .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
        .len = ARRAY_SIZE(tx),
        .delay_usecs = delay,
        .speed_hz = speed,
        .bits_per_word = bits,  //important, bits = 8 means byte transfer is possible
    };

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
    if (ret < 1)
        pabort("can't send spi message\n");

    printf("the received data is below:\n");
    for (ret = 0; ret < ARRAY_SIZE(tx); ret++) {    //print the received data, by Tom Xue
        if (!(ret % 6))
            puts("");
        printf("%.2X ", rx[ret]);
    }
    puts("");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret = 0;
    int fd;

    fd = open(device, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0)
        pabort("can't open device\n");

    /*
     * spi mode
     */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set spi mode\n");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE, &mode);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get spi mode\n");

    /*
     * bits per word
     */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set bits per word\n");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get bits per word\n");

    /*
     * max speed hz
     */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set max speed hz\n");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get max speed hz\n");

    printf("open device: %s\n", device);
    printf("set spi mode: %d\n", mode);
    printf("set bits per word: %d\n", bits);
    printf("set max speed: %d Hz (%d MHz)\n", speed, speed/1000000);

    while(1){
        transfer(fd);
        sleep(1);
    }

    close(fd);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: because it's not supported by the hw implementation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus#Data_transmission . for modern computers' sake, you should set 8 bits per word. have no idea why you try to set bazaar numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I want to drive an Eink driver IC. And the IC needs this kind of spi multi-bytes transfer: 16bits command + multi-word data. @HuStmpHrrr

Comment: you should read the doc. i have no idea what that IC is, but i bet 16 bits per word is the maximum in the industry. don't get confused with the word length and the data length you need to send.